# moment-range.js Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

In a classic angularJS web app I've tried to add moment libraries and the plug in moment-range also.

On my index.html, I've added the following lines :

```
<script src="js/external/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="js/external/moment/moment-range.js"></script>
```

On another file I'm trying to use moment in a simple way :

```
var start = moment($scope.startDate);
var end = moment($scope.endDate);
var range = moment.range(start,end);
$scope.years = Array.from(range.by('year'));
```

When I'm reloading my browser (I've tried both on safari and chrome), I'm getting the following error :

**Chrome** :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

**Safari** :

```
[Error]SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'moment'. import call expects exactly one argument.
(fonction anonyme) (moment-range.js:1)
```

What did I missed ?

[Edit] : I've tried before the lines regarding the creation of the moment vars 'start' and 'end', and it's working. It's really just the import of moment-range that's not working.
Here at the source I'm trying to use :

```
moment.js : http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js
moment-range.js : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rotaready/moment-range/master/lib/moment-range.js
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
window['moment-range'].extendMoment(moment);
```

at the begenning of your script, it is mentioned in documentations under instllation section [here](https://github.com/rotaready/moment-range)

you can add it like this:

```
<script src="js/external/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="js/external/moment/moment-range.js"></script>
<script>
       window['moment-range'].extendMoment(moment);
</script>
```

Comment: On which script ? moment.js or moment-range.js ? I've tried both and I'm still having this issue

Comment: I mean in your javascript code :D
before calling and using range, you can put it before
var start = moment($scope.startDate); line

Comment: Preferably somewhere global so all your angular app, takes effect, updated my answer

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working I've still have the issue but with this following error : TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window['moment-range'].extendMoment')

Comment: Nevermind.. If found out what I've missed.. I've downloaded the wrong moment-range.js.. I've get the one with ES6. Anyway, by adding your line it's working, thanks